# mouseleave event for embed tag

Tags: html, mouseover, mouseleave

I bind a `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events to the `#container` div and the html is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
<a href="#">test</a>
<div class="zclip" id="zclip-ZeroClipboardMovie_2" style="width: 110px; height: 31px;     left: 75px; top: 85px;"><embed width="110" height="31" align="middle" wmode="transparent" flashvars="id=2&amp;width=110&amp;height=31" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" name="ZeroClipboardMovie_2" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="best" menu="false" loop="false" src="/static/js/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf" id="ZeroClipboardMovie_2">    
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, everytime my mouse enters the `.zclip` div and then leave, it will also trigger the `mouseleave` event of the `#container` div even if my mouse is still in the container. There is no such problem for the anchor tag inside the `#container`. I don't know if it has something to do with the `embed` element inside the `.zclip` div. Can someone give me some idea on this?

Comment: could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your situation?

Comment: I recreated as best I could your setup in jsfiddle, and I only see one mouseleave event fired for the entire container. I think we need to see how you are binding those events. http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/6jD3u/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `event.stopPropagation()` in your `mouseleave` event handler

[.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)